# What is the max amount of connections a GeoPackage can handle in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, sqlite, connection, geopackage, database

I'm currently working on a GeoServer deployment and for simplicity, I want to to transition to using GeoPackages rather than Shapefiles (longer column names, less work integrating the data, etc.).

As GeoPackages are based on the SQLite3 standard there's a possibility that, with too many connections, users won't be able to read the polygons saved within a GeoPackage. (Here's a similar discussion on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017762/what-is-the-maximum-connections-for-sqlite3-database)).

I'm not sure whether GeoServer loads shapefiles and other data into a database that can accommodate 100s of users, or if it simply reads shapefiles/other vector data directly when a user demands access to them. While other SE's may know more about DBMSes, I felt this question was appropriate for the GIS SE users who have more likely used GeoServers.

My question is what are the connection limitations for GeoPackages served through GeoServer?

Comment: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geopkg/input.html. The discussion in your link is not appropriate for your use case if your users just read data, not write with WFS-T.

Comment: GeoPackages (like shapefiles) are read at each render, for max performance put your data in a PostGIS DB,

Comment: @Ian with the work I did this winter on geopackage, there should not be significant performance differences left. Do you have tests showing otherwise?

Comment: No, I just always recommend a  DB over files on disk.

Comment: GeoPackage is a database as well and PostGIS data files are also stored on disk. Recommendation should perhaps be based on some other facts.

Comment: its a bit off topic - Geopackages are fundamentally a SQLite database (and I do quite like them), they are perhaps a little less flexible and mature when it comes to advanced RDMS features, compared to postGIS, especially for a high-end database administrator. Perhaps another topic is required for more detailed discussion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no connection limitation if you're using version 2.13.x (warmly recommended, it's significantly faster than older versions when it comes to geopackages), but you'll eventually hit the max number of open files limit (which you can raise, in different ways according to the operating system in use).

Comment: That's great to hear and it clarifies many of my concerns. Thanks! I know this breaks SE conventions, but on a side note, I've been following the discussion concerning SLD loading from GeoPackage to GeoServer. Is there a site/GitHub repo where I can find news on that project? All the best.

Comment: At the moment there is nothing I'm afraid, after the initial impetus the thing seems to have died down... we'll see. Check the geotools project developer list archives and geotools pull request queue.